# keep rightmark clear until section starts

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

I'd like to have the chapter title in the upper left and the section title in the upper right corner of my one-sided document. The upper right corner should only be populated if there actually is a section on that side. My problem can be reproduced with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\automark[section]{chapter}

\ihead[\leftmark]{\leftmark}
\chead{}
\ohead{\rightmark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum \lipsum

\section{section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The `\ohead{\rightmark}` is somewhat by design because I don't want the section title to appear on the first page of a new chapter.

The real problem occurs on page 2, where the header reads "1. chapter .... 1. chapter". How can I get an blank upper right corner?

Sorry for the probably bad title of the question, but if I could make it clearer, google would probably help to solve the problem...

Comment: Hi and welcome, good example, i'll have a look at this. But please note, that `scrpage2` development has stopped. It's current status is `deprecated`. The successor is `scrlayer-scrpage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `scrpage2` is depreciated. The successor is `scrlayer-scrpage`.

You can use `\ifstr` from the `scrbase` package:

```
\ohead{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{}{\rightmark}}
```

The package `scrbase` is loaded by the KOMA-Script class and the command is explained in the KOMA-Script documentation [scrguien.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf):

> `\ifstr{<string>}{<string>}{<then instructions>}{<else instructions>}`
>
> Both `<string>` arguments are expanded and afterwards compared. If the
>   expansions are the same, the `<then instructions>` will be executed,
>   otherwise the `<else instructions>`.

This will also work in the table of contents or with `\addchap` and `\addsec`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead[\leftmark]{\leftmark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{}{\rightmark}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}
\Blindtext[10]
\section{section}
\Blindtext

\addchap{chapter}
\Blindtext[10]
\addsec{section}
\Blindtext

\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that there is a star version of `\ihead` in the new [KOMA-Script version 3.14](http://www.komascript.de/release3.14) which allows to use `\ihead*{\leftmark}` instead of `\ihead[\leftmark]{\leftmark}`. Unfortunaly, this version is not yet on CTAN.

---

The suggestion with the depriacted `scrpage2`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead[\leftmark]{\leftmark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{}{\rightmark}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{chapter}
\Blindtext[10]
\section{section}
\Blindtext

\addchap{chapter}
\Blindtext[10]
\addsec{section}
\Blindtext

\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have to say, the starred versions of `\ihead` and others are very very comfortable.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it seems to be sematically cleaner to me. Could you please include a small note on \ifstr? I guess it works like "if #1 == #2 then #3 else #4"?

Answer (score 2):

With your current setup, it's sufficient to patch `\chaptermark` `A`t the `B`eginning of the `D`ocument to call `\@mkboth` with only the left mark used; keeping the right mark empty:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\chaptermark}% <cmd>
    {\@mkboth}% <search>
    {\chaptermkboth}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
  }
\newcommand{\chaptermkboth}[2]{\@mkboth{#1}{}}
\makeatother
```

There are other uses of `\@mkboth` inside `\chaptermark`, but the first seems to be the most important in this case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\automark[section]{chapter}

\ihead[\leftmark]{\leftmark}
\chead{}
\ohead{\rightmark}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \patchcmd{\chaptermark}% <cmd>
    {\@mkboth}% <search>
    {\chaptermkboth}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
  }
\newcommand{\chaptermkboth}[2]{\@mkboth{#1}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum \lipsum

\section{section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you add a hint on the successor `scrlayer-scrpage` i can delete the comment to the Q.